# Create yara file to return match on hex string

Tags: yara

I'm on Mac os12.2.1 trying to run yara where it returns a match using basic hex string content.

Yara rule (file name: rulehexstr)
 `rule hex_new {   strings: $hexnew = { 48 65 6c 6c 6f } condition: $hexnew }`

For the yara file, I used `echo -n "HELLO" | od -A n -t x1 > inputfile`.

So, when I call `yara rulehexstr inputfile`, I expect output of `hex_new inputfile`, but it returns nothing.

How do I create a file that will return a match on the above rule?

Answer (score 0):

My hex was wrong for uppercase letters. And using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521240/how-to-create-binary-file-using-bash) post, I did
`echo -n $'\x48\x45\x4c\x4c\x4f' > filehexstr-uppercase-hello.dat`

Then, running `yara rulehexstr filehexstr-uppercase-hello.dat` returned `hex_new filehexstr-uppercase-hello.dat`.